# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'does_not_exist' while running .py script for zap testing

Tags: python, error-handling, zap

I was doing Zap test on two .Net micro services and automated the process with Git Actions, The work flow was running fine without any error but as soon as I updated the code base and added feature flags in my code it
returned above mentioned error. Below is the .py file

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
   import time
   import datetime
   import os
   import requests
   from pprint import pprint
   from pprint import pprint
   from zapv2 import ZAPv2 
   from zapv2 import ZAPv2 as ZAP
   from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

   # The URL of the application to be tested
   target = 'http://localhost:5074/hello'
   # Change to match the API key set in ZAP, or use None if the API key is 
   disabled
   apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

   firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
   firefox_options.headless = True

   # By default ZAP API client will connect to port 8080
   # zap = ZAPv2(apikey=apiKey)
   # Use the line below if ZAP is not listening on port 8080, for example, 
   if listening on port 8090
   zap = ZAPv2(apikey=apiKey, proxies={'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8090', 
   'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8090'})

   print('Spidering target {}'.format(target))
   # The scan returns a scan id to support concurrent scanning
   scanID = zap.spider.scan(target)
   while int(zap.spider.status(scanID)) < 100:
       # Poll the status until it completes
       print('Spider progress %: {}'.format(zap.spider.status(scanID)))
       time.sleep(1)

   print('Spider has completed!')
   # Prints the URLs the spider has crawled
   print('\n'.join(map(str, zap.spider.results(scanID))))
   # If required post process the spider results

   # TODO: Explore the Application more with Ajax Spider or Start scanning 
   the application for vulnerabilities

   print('Ajax Spider target {}'.format(target))
   scanID = zap.ajaxSpider.scan(target)

   timeout = time.time() + 60*2   # 2 minutes from now
   # Loop until the ajax spider has finished or the timeout has exceeded
   while zap.ajaxSpider.status == 'running':
       if time.time() > timeout:
           break
       print('Ajax Spider status' + zap.ajaxSpider.status)
       time.sleep(2)

   print('Ajax Spider completed')
   ajaxResults = zap.ajaxSpider.results(start=0, count=10)
   # If required perform additional operations with the Ajax Spider results

   # TODO: Start scanning the application to find vulnerabilities
   print('Active Scanning target {}'.format(target))
   scanID = zap.ascan.scan(target)
   print(scanID)
   print(zap.ascan.status(scanID))
   while int(zap.ascan.status(scanID)) < 100:
       # Loop until the scanner has finished
       print('Scan progress %: {}'.format(zap.ascan.status(scanID)))
       time.sleep(25)

   print('Active Scan completed')
   # Print vulnerabilities found by the scanning
   print('Hosts: {}'.format(', '.join(zap.core.hosts)))
   print('Alerts: ')
   pprint(zap.core.alerts(baseurl=target))

   ###########
   alerts = zap.core.alerts(baseurl=target)
   print('Alerts: ')
   pprint(alerts)

   with open("zap-alerts.txt", "w") as f:
       f.write("Alerts:\n")
       for alert in alerts:
           f.write(str(alert) + "\n")


   # Shut down ZAP
   zap.core.shutdown()
```

Below is the specific error I am encountering

```
    Ajax Spider completed
Active Scanning target http://localhost:5074/hello
url_not_found
does_not_exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cl/Desktop/Feature-toggling /sample-services/Sample-services/zap-testing.py", line 60, in <module>
    while int(zap.ascan.status(scanID)) < 100:
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'does_not_exist'
```

I searched for alternative way to convert the following to int but I failed, Can anyone please guide me with this error.

Comment: You can see that `zap.ascan.status(scanID)` is returning "does_not_exist" probably because `zap.ascan.scan(target)` returns "url_not_found". Are you sure you van visit `http://localhost:5074/hello`? perhaps check with your browser or curl. Perhaps that service is not running or is firewalled.

Comment: Hello JonSG, Actually when I run the script locally it runs but when I try to run my workflow (GitHub actions) I encounter this error, Basically I got two .Net micro services and both are dockerized and are up when docker compose up executes in my workflow.
And thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the docker compose file as after adjusting the flags the services utilized port 8080 instead of 80. I updated it an all is fine now.